# PHP hide data IF mysql string empty

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I have some PHP that's pulling MySQL entries into an HTML table. The table headers are still visible when there are no results provided by the query so I wanted to use an IF function to display an alternate message on the front end.

My so far limited knowledge of PHP means I'm struggling to find any way to check the results. Every method I've come across online had been a dead end.

Can anybody see what I'm missing please?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM stock WHERE (SKU='$SKUsearch1' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch2' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch3' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch4' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch5' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch6' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch7' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch8' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch9' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch10' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch11' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch12' AND Location='London Store') ");


if (!$row['Location']) {

                echo "<table class='availableTable' border='1'>
                <tr>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Availability</th>
                </tr>";

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";

                if(($row['Available']) > 0) {
                echo "<td> In Stock </td>";
                }
                else {
                echo "<td> Out of Stock </td>";
                }

                echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";




}

else {

        echo "<div class='availableText'>No instore stock information is currently available for this product.</div>";

}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend changing that SELECT statement to something like: `Location='London Store' AND SKU IN (....)`

Comment: Where is `$row` defined? It looks like it's being used in the IF statement before it's defined

Comment: I suspect @dustytrash nailed it. If not, please edit your question to include the output you are getting.

Comment: @dustytrash Gotcha. I was looking for a better method. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$row['Location']** **$row** is not available before while loop

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM stock WHERE (SKU='$SKUsearch1' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch2' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch3' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch4' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch5' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch6' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch7' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch8' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch9' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch10' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch11' AND Location='London Store') OR (SKU='$SKUsearch12' AND Location='London Store') ");


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {

                    echo "<table class='availableTable' border='1'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Availability</th>
                    </tr>";

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                    {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";

                    if(($row['Available']) > 0) {
                    echo "<td> In Stock </td>";
                    }
                    else {
                    echo "<td> Out of Stock </td>";
                    }

                    echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";




        }

        else {

                echo "<div class='availableText'>No instore stock information is currently available for this product.</div>";
    }
```

try **mysqli_num_rows($result)** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php